# Android Instant App in different project/branch

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I have a normal installable app on my git main branch. Now I want to create an Instant version of that game on a branch. I have done everything as described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle). And at [version-codes](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#version-codes) it also says:

> It's OK to develop your instant app and your installable app in two separate Android Studio projects.

This is, I guess, the same as having a separate branch.

This is what I have changed:

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app.package"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="2">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application ...>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.instant.flavor" android:value="1337"/>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The `targetSandboxVersion`, `dist:module` and the `meta-data`.

In build.gradle I have added `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.1"` and set `versionCode` to 1.

But when I upload the app bundle it says that `versionCode 1` is already used. But according to the quote above I think it should be possible to upload a bundle that only has the instant version. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For Instant App use version code lower than the version code of the standard/not-instant app.
It allows install of the standard version from the Instant version.

If you already have uploaded standard version, increase it's version code to eg. 100 and re-upload the standard version. Than use version code lower than 100 for the instant app.

Make sure app-bundle or apk with specific version code was not already uploaded, this includes also apk-s and bundles unsuccessfully uploaded and includes all versions of the app, both standard and instant.